# request data Post from java script to aiohttp server

Tags: javascript, python, html, post, aiohttp

I am trying to post data - userWallet- to my aiohttp server. I want it to check if address is not null, so that i know that the connection was successful than redirect to a new page.

I am able to get conection to metamask, and redirect manually, as metamask stays connected.

I did somethin similar but only with  so i am not sure how to do it.

Thanks for your help

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Metamask login</title>
        <link href="https://unpkg.com/tailwindcss@^1.0/dist/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    
    <body class="flex w-screen h-screen justify-center items-center">
        <div class="flex-col space-y-2 justify-center items-center">
        <button id="LoginButton" onclick="" class="btn rounded-full p-2 bg-blue-400 hover:text-white hover:bg-blue-700 hover:border-transparent">
          Log into your metamask
        </button>
        <br>
        <p id='userWallet'></p>
       </div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            
            const LoginButton = document.getElementById('LoginButton')
        
            function toggleButton() {
                if (!window.ethereum) {
                    LoginButton.innerText = 'MetaMask is not installed'
                    LoginButton.classList.remove('bg-purple-500', 'text-white')
                    LoginButton.classList.add('bg-gray-500', 'text- gray-100', 'cursor-not-allowed')
                    return false
                }
                LoginButton.addEventListener('click', LoginWithMetamask)
            }
            async function LoginWithMetamask(){
                const accounts = await window.ethereum.request({method:'eth_requestAccounts' })
                    .catch((e) => {
                        console.error(e.message)
                        return
                    })

                if (!accounts) { return }

                window.userWalletAddress = accounts[0]
                userWallet.innerText = window.userWalletAddress
                LoginButton.innerText = 'Proceed'

                LoginButton.removeEventListener('click', LoginWithMetamask)
                setTimeout(() => {
                LoginButton.addEventListener('click', signOutOfMetaMask)
                }, 200)
            }

            window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
                toggleButton()
            });
            function signOutOfMetaMask() {

            }
            function signOutOfMetaMask() {
                window.userWalletAddress = null
                userWallet.innerText = ''
                LoginButton.innerText = 'Sign in with MetaMask'

                LoginButton.removeEventListener('click', signOutOfMetaMask)
                setTimeout(() => {
                    LoginButton.addEventListener('click', LoginWithMetamask)
                }, 200)
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

and my python code:

```
from aiohttp import web
import asyncio
import jinja2
import aiohttp_jinja2
import os

routes = web.RouteTableDef()


@routes.get('/')
async def handler(request):
    with open('templates/loginpage.html', 'rb') as f:
            return web.Response(
                body=f.read().decode('utf8'),
                content_type='text/html')
                
#the manual redirect testpage
@routes.get('/testpage')
async def metamask_login(request):
    with open('templates/testpage.html', 'rb') as f:
        
        return web.Response(
        body=f.read().decode('utf8'),
        content_type='text/html')
                
@routes.post('/somenewpage')
async def post_wallet():
    #some code here
    pass

async def init_app() -> web.Application:
    app = web.Application()
    aiohttp_jinja2.setup(
    app, loader=jinja2.FileSystemLoader(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "templates"))
)

    app.add_routes(routes)
    return app


if __name__ == '__main__':

    web.run_app(init_app())
```

Comment: Can you clarify where the problem is - is it the Javascript or the Python code?

Comment: I just cant figure the solution to post it from Java script to the aiohttp server, and then redirect. The java script is working